First call to ArangoDb very slow (20 seconds) following calls fast
I've got ArangoDb running in Docker like this:
docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 -p 8529:8529 -d -v C:\Programming\xxx\arangodb:/var/lib/arangodb3 arangodb

And I'm connecting to it using ArangoDBNetStandard in the most usual way from the examples:
var transport = HttpApiTransport.UsingBasicAuth(
    new Uri(host),  // "http://localhost:8529"
    dbName,
    user,
    pass);
db = new ArangoDBClient(transport);

It takes forever for the first connection. That is, not the call to connect (the db = ...) but the first call to await db.Document.GetDocumentAsync, or db.Graph.GetGraphAsync. It doesn't matter what. Subsequent calls are fast.
This is very visible in Unit tests, where the first test takes 20+ seconds, and the rest are almost instant.
One weird (but perhaps telling) trait is that if I pause before the first ...Get call, but after db = new... for more than 20 seconds, it's also fast.
So it seems there has to pass some time between connecting to the db, and issuing the first call. After that it's OK for a while. If I wait for a long time before issuing new requests (not from UT but from my web app), then I get the long wait.
My guess is that there's some timeout somewhere, some certificate issue or something (IDK because the HttpApiTransport is HTTP, not HTTPS, right), but this is what it feels like.
Any tips? I think it started after upgrading Docker Desktop (on Windows w. WSL2), but I can't be 100% sure.

I've seen this in even MYSQL, I got a giant set of procedures and it takes about 2 seconds for the first pull, then every pull after is about 0.7 to 1.2 seconds or so.  I wonder if your db supports a task scheduler and you could maybe have it trying to pull a generic pull every 15 seconds or something, and see if it being "warm" makes it load quicker on first access?

That could solve it, as a workaround. Since it just started to behave this way, I have hope of finding the underlying problem

I hear you there, am curious to see if it helps though if you do deploy it keep me posted.

I've reinstalled old version of Docker Desktop (v.4.24.0) and Arango container (3.11.4), and this combination does not have the problem. I'll incrementally increase the versions to try to find where the problem lies (DD or A).

Interesting, perhaps its some sort of bug that could be reported or looked into for the upgrade?
